# Image not loading in IE but loads in all other browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have a form where user can upload images of their interest to lock them in the UI Logo place. So, when uploading these images through form, once after the user uploads and fires save the button which displays a 40*40px image in the form to display what the user has uploaded previously. This 40*40px image clearly visible in all browsers but not in IE8, IE9, IE11. I have tried many solutions after searching around and got tired. Can any one help why this not happening in IE.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the form with "Img" tag inside

```
<form:form id="submitform"  action="updatePolicyLogo.non" name="policyLogosForm" modelAttribute="policyLogos" method="POST" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>
    <label for="policyId" title='<spring:message code="tt.mysettings.policy" />'><spring:message    code="label.policy" /></label>
    <form:select id="policyId" path="policyId" style="width:160px;">
        <form:options items="${policies}" itemValue="value" itemLabel="label" htmlEscape="false" />
    </form:select>
    <br/>
    <label for="policyLogo"> <spring:message code="label.policy.logo.current" /></label>
    <img id="existingImageId" src="icons/icn_delete.png"/> 
    <a id="deleteImageId"> <img id="deleteImg" src="icons/icn_delete.png"  style="margin-top:6px"/> </a>
    <div id="noneLogo"> <spring:message code="label.policy.logo.none" /> </div>
    <br/>
    <label> <spring:message code="label.policy.logo.new" /></label>  <form:input id="policyLogo" path="policyLogo" style="width:160px;" type="file" accept="image/*" />
    <form:errors path="policyLogo" />                
</fieldset>

<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value='<spring:message code="label.button.save" />' />
</div>
```

i am adding the image through Jquery here.

```
$("#existingImageId").attr("src", "getLogo.ams?id="+selectedPolicyId).bind('load', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#noneLogo").css('display', 'none');
        $("#existingImageId").css('display', 'block');
        $("#deleteImg").css('display', 'block');
        alert("src");
    });
```

In Chrome, I get the following HTML after loaded

```
<form id="submitform" name="policyLogosForm" action="updatePolicyLogo.ams" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off">
<fieldset>
    <label for="policyId" title="Policy must be accessible by creator.">Policy</label>
    <select id="policyId" name="policyId" style="width:160px;">
        <option value="1" selected="selected">All Policies</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="policyLogo"> Current Logo</label>
    <img id="existingImageId" src="getLogo.ams?id=1" style="display: block;"> 
    <a id="deleteImageId"> <img id="deleteImg" src="icons/icn_delete.png" style="margin-top: 6px; display: block;"> </a>
    <div id="noneLogo" style="display: none;"> No Logo Selected. </div>
    <br>
    <label> New Logo</label>  <input id="policyLogo" name="policyLogo" style="width:160px;" accept="image/*" type="file" value="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@16860f88">

</fieldset>

<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Save">
</div>
```

I also found some related issues which can't have a solution here http://madebyted.com/blog/using-images-as-labels-inside-forms-in-internet-explorer-11/ and https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/40

Comment: it says selectedPolicyId is undefined;

**add** **var selectedPolicyId ="";**

$("#existingImageId").attr("src", "getLogo.ams?id="+selectedPolicyId).bind('load', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#noneLogo").css('display', 'none');
        $("#existingImageId").css('display', 'block');
        $("#deleteImg").css('display', 'block');
        alert("src");
    });

Comment: Sorry there is some other code which i did not posted here, in there selectedPolicyId was defined.

Comment: is it possible to post the code in jsfiddle with dummy images, you can get the lots of dummy images from google, or serch for image in jsfiddle